# Why are the unwrapped UV faces different sizes and proportions to my model's faces?

Tags: texturing, uv, uv-image-editor

Hey so I'm fairly new to Blender and am having issues with some of my UV unwraps. The lines in the UV Image Editor are making completely different shapes. I've tried multiple things trying to get them to be more uniform with their model but it still isn't working. Not sure if it's how I'm doing my seams or something else. Let me know what you think.

[image: **enter image description here**]

[image]

Comment: Hi. Are you trying to say that your UVs are laid out how you want (on the right) but they're not showing correctly in the 3D View (left) or that the faces are not being unwrapped how you want?

Comment: It seem you have many extraordinary faces in your mesh. Could you upload your file? https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/

Comment: The outlines on the right side aren't at all right, they're different sizes, shapes, and proportions than what they should be as on the model on the left, and yeah ill upload the file!

Comment: [<img src="https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/embedImage.png?bid=6553" />](https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/b/6553/)

Comment: Try to avoid the concave faces. Blender really bed at unwrapping them. In this case that would be the best if you create a grid on the whole object with "ctrl+r" or subdividing an then extrude the coffin holes inside with "e".

Answer (score 1):

You can try to use a front orthographic view, select some faces and choose U - project from view. Then change the view and go on with other faces, until you unwrap the whole model.

The classic UV algorithm gets confused by your convex Ngons, a clear topology, with only not convex quads, would avoid the problems.

[image]

Comment: Yeah that really helped thank you! Im just wondering how I am able to keep all of the unwraps on the same map? Whenever I go to a new side and uv map it from the project view it removes the ones I had previously?

Comment: UV editor will show all selected faces, so you can simply select all unwrapped areas, so they all will be showed and you will be able to move, rotate and resize them.